# Navigation from game canvas to a form

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

How do you navigate from a game canvas to a form in Java ME when you require a user to insert his or her username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Create the form and add some "OK" command to it.

To show the form, you have to do the following:

```
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(yourForm);
```

When that OK command is used, you should do:

```
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(yourCanvas);
```

and read the data from the form